# The class 'org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_2' does not have the property

Tags: jsf-2.2, seam, seam2, jboss-seam

I am learning seam framework and was going through the examples given with seam package. I am trying to declare a property in a seam component and refer it in jsf. But, I am getting an error saying the class does not have the property.

My seam component is as follows:

**Register.java interface**

```
package org.jboss.seam.example.registration;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface Register
{
   public String register();
}
```

**RegisterAction.java class**

```
@Stateless
@Name("register")
public class RegisterAction implements Register
{
   private String college;

   public String getCollege() {
    return college;
}
public void setCollege(String college) {
    this.college = college;
}
```

**register.xhtml file**

```
<h:inputText id="college" value="#{register.college}" required="true"/>
```

While deploying the application and accessing the link: http://localhost:8080/seam-registration/register.seam

**I am getting the below error:**

```
Context Path:/seam-registration
Servlet Path:/register.seam
Path Info:null
Query String:null
Stack Trace
javax.servlet.ServletException: /register.xhtml @24,99 value="#{register.college}": The class 'org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_2' does not have the property 'college'.
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**The server log is below:**

```
09:26:52,777 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-12) Error Rendering View[/register.xhtml]: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /register.xhtml @24,99 value="#{register.college}": The class 'org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_2' does not have the property 'college'.
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
        at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
        at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
        at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.cdk.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:186)
        at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.cdk.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:166)
        at org.jboss.seam.ui.renderkit.ValidateAllRendererBase.doEncodeChildren(ValidateAllRendererBase.java:35)
        at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.cdk.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:92)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
        at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamViewHandler.renderView(SeamViewHandler.java:188)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_2' does not have the property 'college'.
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:568)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:229)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
        at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.getValue(AstPropertySuffix.java:53)
        at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:67)
        at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        ... 69 more

09:26:52,779 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-12) UT005023: Exception handling request to /seam-registration/register.seam: javax.servlet.ServletException: /register.xhtml @24,99 value="#{register.college}": The class 'org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_2' does not have the property 'college'.
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /register.xhtml @24,99 value="#{register.college}": The class 'org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_2' does not have the property 'college'.
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
        at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
        at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
        at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.cdk.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:186)
        at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.cdk.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:166)
        at org.jboss.seam.ui.renderkit.ValidateAllRendererBase.doEncodeChildren(ValidateAllRendererBase.java:35)
        at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.cdk.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:92)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
        at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamViewHandler.renderView(SeamViewHandler.java:188)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_2' does not have the property 'college'.
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:568)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:229)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
        at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.getValue(AstPropertySuffix.java:53)
        at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:67)
        at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        ... 69 more
```

Comment: The confusing part is, if i don't implement the interface Register, then it works fine. It shows me the page with the input box. I cannot workout what different the interface makes here.

Answer (score 0):

the exception is speaking itself, Seam proxy your class and mapp it to your interface as a result #{register} value expression refers to the interface which does not contain getter/setter for college field. you don't need to use EJB most of the time remove the interface and use a class only.

```
@Name("register") //or even better @Name("registerAction")
@Scope(Conversation)
public class RegisterAction
{
   private String college;

   public String getCollege() {
    return college;
}
public void setCollege(String college) {
    this.college = college;
}

}
```